# value reduceByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)] after import

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I created this RDD :

```
scala> val data=sc.textFile("sparkdata.txt")
```

Then I am trying to return the content of the file :

```
scala> data.collect
```

I am dividing existing data in individual word using :

```
scala> val splitdata = data.flatMap(line => line.split(" "));
scala> splitdata.persist()
scala> splitdata.collect;
```

Now, I am doing the map reduce operation :

```
scala> val mapdata = splitdata.map(word => (word,1));
scala> mapdata.collect;
scala> val reducedata = mapdata.reduceByKey(_+_);
```

To get the result :

```
scala> reducedata.collect;
```

When I want to display the first 10th rows :

```
splitdata.groupByKey(identity).count().show(10)
```

I get the following error :

```
<console>:38: error: value groupByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
       splitdata.groupByKey(identity).count().show(10)
                 ^
<console>:38: error: missing argument list for method identity in object Predef
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `identity _` or `identity(_)` instead of `identity`.
       splitdata.groupByKey(identity).count().show(10)
                            ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to `reduceByKey()`, [`groupByKey()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@groupByKey():org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD%5B(K,Iterable%5BV%5D)%5D) is a method for `PairRDD`s of type `RDD[K, V]`, rather than for general `RDD`s.  While `reduceByKey()` uses a provided binary function to reduce a `RDD[K, V]` to another `RDD[K, V]`, `groupByKey()` transforms a `RDD[K, V]` into a `RDD[(K, Iterable[V])]`.  To further transform the `Iterable[V]` by key, one would typically apply [`mapValues()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@mapValues%5BU%5D(f:V=%3EU):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD%5B(K,U)%5D) (or `flatMapValues`) with a provided function.

For example:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  "apple", "apple", "orange", "banana", "banana", "orange", "apple", "apple", "orange"
))

rdd.map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).collect
// res1: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((apple,4), (banana,2), (orange,3))

rdd.map((_, 1)).groupByKey().mapValues(_.sum).take(2)
// res2: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((apple,4), (banana,2))
```

In case you're interested only in getting the count of groups after applying `groupByKey()`:

```
rdd.map((_, 1)).groupByKey().count()
// res3: Long = 3
```